# Sony Remote Camera API sample Android app - Android Studio

Tags: camera, sony

I am having difficulty running the Android sample application for the Sony Action Cam API in Android Studio.  I've tried to import the project into Android Studio, but I must not be configuring all the settings properly.  Has anyone done this that can provide a step by step.  My only experience with Android development was in Eclipse, but I want to try Android Studio as its the latest technology.

Maybe Sony can create a version of this project for Android Studio and make it available from the download page. Please!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build and run the latest (SDK 1.90) sample app after importing the CameraRemoteSampleApp sample project into Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.14. Please check again.

Best Regards, Prem, Developer World team